# How do I program my code so when I press a key it runs a different script?

Tags: c++

I am compleatly new to coding and my first project is to take something already made and change it in several ways to teach myself the basics. I have chosen to use FizzBuzz, where on multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz".

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
        else
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                cout << "Fizz" << endl;
            else
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                    cout << "Buzz" << endl;
                else cout << i << endl;

    }
    system("sleep");
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is: instead of the program printing "Fizz" on multiples of three it does it on multiple of 4 and it prints "Buzz" for multiples of 6 instead of 5 when I press a key

I am struggling on figuring out how to change the code on a key press. Thank you.

Comment: Start out by writing out the algorithm the program will follow in as much detail as you can. Specify when it waits for input, how it validates the input, what it does with the input, and so on. Post what you've come up with and ask a specific question about where you get stuck.

Comment: This is the very first thing I am doing. I do not know how to write code when you press any key it and runs a few more lines of code. I have tried google ing it but I think im being to broad.

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you're trying to do, you will have a problem pressing a button before the program ends.

Comment: Assuming you are running on windows, the _kbhit() and _getch() functions may be what you are looking for:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit

Comment: @JeremyFriesner how would I go around in implementing that into my code?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place that teaches programming. You are expected to know how to write code.

Comment: I don't think he needs any of that stuff. He just needs to take basic numeric input and process it.

Comment: @Olly Do you know how to write out an algorithm in english? If not, learn how. If so, edit your question to explain in words what algorithm you want the program to follow or to ask a specific question in figuring that out.